# 'result' stays null even when I put in the correct number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx

I don't get any errors but when I run the React Native app `result` will stay `false`. When I click on `Generate Number` - `undefined` will print to the console, but a random number will appear under the `TextInput` and when I click again, a new number will appear but the old number will be printed to the console. This is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState();
  const [result, setResult] = useState(false);

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
  });

  const guess = (num) => {
    if (num === number) {
      setResult(true);
    } else {
      setResult(false);
    }
    console.log(result);
  };

  const genNumber = () => {
    setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1));
    console.log(number);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <Button onPress={() => genNumber()} title="Generate Number" />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.text}
        onChangeText={(text) => guess(text)}
        placeholder="Enter your guess"
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>{number}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Its probably a scope error but im not sure.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous so the following `console.log` may print out of the order

Comment: What you can do instead is declare an effect which is the behaviour you want associates with updates to the state. In your case `useEffect(()=>console.log(nnumber),[nnumber])`

Answer (score 0):

`useState` is asynchronous, as mentioned in the comment, so you either can subscribe to a state changes with `useEffect` or you can do this:

```
const genNumber = async () => {
  await setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1));
  console.log(number);
};
```

Comment: I tried making `genNumber` async but that didn't change anything.